# SSRS How to calculate Moving Range

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2017

```
Year    Sales   Moving Range
2000    6461    
2001    3459    -3002
2002    4595    1136
2003    9726    5131
2004    7109    -2617
2005    8576    1467
2006    2962    -5614
2007    7203    4241
```

I have a dataset similar to the above and need to calculate the Moving Range, which is Value deduct from the the previous value. This is very easy in excel. Can someone help me please Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `PREVIOUS`

If your dataset looks like your example (except for the 'Moving range') then you can simply do

```
=Fields!Sales.Value - PREVIOUS(Fields!Sales.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. You asnwered my question.